# java function return more state types that Boolean

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, enums

If I have just two states(true and false), my function can return boolean and based on its return value I can do some stuff.

```
boolean checkFoo(Object foo) {

 // .....
 return true/false;
}
```

and if I have four states:

I can use enum and use that return enum from function..

```
 public enum StateEnum { //... }

 StateEnum checkFoo(Object foo) {

 // .....
 return StateEnum.STATE1/StateEnum.STATE2/StateEnum.STATE3/StateEnum.STATE4;
}
```

but this enum just used for this function and has no other uses, is there any other clean way for this situation? something like returning string??

Comment: An enum is perfectly fine. It doesn't have to be used for something else to become useful.

Comment: It is fine. I suppose

Comment: You can add StateEnum.toString which will convert to a string when you want to. I agree with the first comment

Comment: Don't return String - the list of valid return values won't be obvious (you can explain in comments, but that's a poor substitute for multiple reasons) and it's easy to mess it up by misspelling something (which would be a runtime error instead of a compile-time one).

Comment: Note that even if you are only returning two states, boolean isn't necessarily the right choice. It is only the correct choice if the return value is something that is true or false. But if you're returning a value to indicate "salt" or "pepper", boolean would be a terrible choice; an enum is a good choice.

Comment: Change StateEnum to FooState and provide meaningful FooStates(not STATE1, 2, 3, 4) and you will have an intuitive solution to your situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enum looks good.

The enum will be in fact used not only by this function, but also by all its clients, and it can be any number of them.

Enum is definitely a better way to go than a string, because you limit the number of possible return values to 4 (in your case).

Answer (score 1):

Have a `Enum` example with below source code:

```
public class DirectionExample {

    public enum Direction {
        EAST, WEST, NORTH, SOUTH;
    }

    public Direction validateDirection(final String direction) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return Direction.valueOf(direction);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            DirectionExample example = new DirectionExample();
            System.out.println(example.validateDirection("EAST").name());

            // Get ready to catch Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
            // No enum constant DirectionExample.Direction.east
            System.out.println(example.validateDirection("east").name());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            System.err.println(iae);
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Fixed Return Type using enum");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an exact answer to your problem but could be an alternative.

If the `StateEnum` is not being used elsewhere then it sounds like you are leaking the internal state of the `foo` object.

What you should really be doing is telling `foo` to evaluate it's state, i.e. tell don't ask (https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html). This keeps the state encapsulated. For example you could have something like this:

```
class Foo {

    private State state;

    bool isParticularState() {
        return state == ...;
    }

    bool isSomeOtherState() {
        return state == ...;
    }
}
```

You can use either an enum or perhaps try the State design pattern to represent the state of the `foo`.

This isn't an ideal solution but I think it keeps the state a little more encapsulated than the original code.

Comment: Returning an enum to represent the result of a method call doesn't sound like leaking the internal state of an object - it just tells you what that one method did (the method might even be static) (at least in general - sometimes it might tell you more about the state of the object than it should, in which case something like what you describe *might* make sense).

Comment: Returning an enum leaks no more state than returning anything else that conveys simply the result of the method. It is simply a matter of the representation of that result. I mean, you could return the same amount of information in an int or a string; but these are simply less convenient to interpret.

Comment: @Dukeling @AndyTurner If the enum represents the state of the `foo` rather than the state of something else then I believe it is leaking the internal state. That's how the `checkFoo()` reads to me; that the state of the `foo` object is being inspected and returned via a `StateEnum`.

Comment: @Kerri if your method returns a value, and the returned value in some sense represents the internal state, you're not *leaking* it: you are *intentionally* exposing it. If you don't want to expose that state, make the method `void`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Ok. I think we are getting hung up on semantics here. Whether intentional or not, the state of the `foo` is being returned from the method. I think the basic point i'm trying to make is that it's not very object oriented IMHO. Or maybe I've just misinterpreted the original code.